# Attempting to Input a record into a Table using a button and text boxes

Tags: database, vba, ms-access

I am struggling to get this bit of code to work in MS Access:

```
Private Sub BtnIssue_Click()

Dim db As Database
Dim rec As Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rec = db.OpenRecordset("Select * from Current_Rentals")

rec.AddNew
rec("Game") = Me.Text85
rec("Game_Copy") = Me.Text77
rec("Member") = Me.Combo111
rec("Issue_Date") = Me.Text154
rec.Update

Set rec = Nothing
Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```

The problem is that Access complains about a compile error, *"user-defined type not defined"*.

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: Just tried your code and it worked just fine. What is the error and at which line is it highlighting?

Comment: If I were the teacher I would downvote, erm downgrade, your work for control names like `Text85` or `Combo111`. Meaningful names are a lot better.

Comment: Compile Error user-defined type not defined and yeah i know about the control names this was just a quick thing i knocked up so i can test things without affecting my final project.

Comment: Is this cheating or did the professor explicitly tell you that you may use any resource?

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob she has taught us how to normilise data and that is all, when it came to the project she says that we need to lean it all from other resourses like books and forums.

Comment: Private Sub BtnIssue_Click()

Comment: What libraries DO you have referenced?

Comment: <https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/225962>

Comment: thank you @JohnWFowler that was the issue, i am over the moon

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim rec as dao.recordset
Set rec = db.openrecordset("current_rentals",dbopendynaset)
```

Comment: i tried this but it came up with the same error Compile Error user-defined type not defined

Comment: If its old access you may need a reference to the dao library?

Comment: Check the name property of your controls.  Maybe the controlsource (field in your table) is as put in your code but the form control name is different.   The debugger should point it right out to you.

Comment: The debugger points to this Private Sub BtnIssue_Click() and i have checked everything and it all looks in order as far as i can see